# Is it possible to verify a samba user's password remotely without mounting a drive?

Tags: command-line, bash, password, samba, authentication

I have a user script which mounts a samba drive using cifs, from the command line. I would like to be able to query whether the password provided is correct, before attempting to mount the share. How would I go about achieving this?

Comment: Are you verifying the user password or the samba password? If it's the password for the samba share, remove the password option from the mount command and it will prompt for a password.

Comment: It's the user's password for the samba share, created with the normal smbpasswd command. I want to check that authentication will succeed before mounting the drive, there are other processes I need to do before mounting, but want to ensure that the auth stage will be passed before doing them.